# Convert to Islam and marriage related issues

Tags: nikah, conversion

Asalam walekum

I am in great trouble , I need your help .

I am an Hindu divorce mother, my child's age is 9 and custody of child is with my ex husband.

I came to know about Islam from one of my friend who is Momidian  . I started listening to  bayan and reading about Islam,i following Islam as much I can and  I want to convert to Islam  ,can I covert into Islam? 
My second concern is I want to marry one of my Muslim college friend he to wants to marry me 
 please please guide me  according to shariah can I marry a Muslim man

Answer (score 1):

Yes, anyone can convert to Islam. If you convert to Islam you can marry a Muslim man.